# Issue with accessing JSON Covid Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**Background on my application**

I am using react and node js. I connected node.js to react.js using axios.

**Issue**

I'm trying to access the cases (5226) in Afganistan, but I can't seem to get the right variable for it.

```
const cases = covidData[0].cases
```

Whenever, i try to run the app using nodemon (to run my server) and npm start (to run my react app) I get the following error on my terminal

Error from node terminal

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./server.js`
listening at port 5000
200
undefined:1
[{"updated":1589436777722,"country":"Afghanistan","countryInfo":{"_id":4,"iso2":"AF","iso3":"AFG","lat":33,"long":65,"flag":"https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/af.png"},"cases":5226,"todayCases":0,"deaths":132,"todayDeaths":0,"recovered":648,"active":4446,"critical":7,"casesPerOneMillion":134,"deathsPerOneMillion":3,"tests":18724,"testsPerOneMillion":481,"continent":"Asia"},{"updated":1589436777821,"country":"Albania","countryInfo":{"_id":8,"iso2":"AL","iso3":"ALB","lat":41,"long":20,"flag":"https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/al.png"},"cases":880,"todayCases":0,"deaths":31,"todayDeaths":0,"recovered"


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/alfietorres/github/covid19/server.js:13:30)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:504:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:973:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:954:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

JSON from website

```
[
 {
 "updated": 1589433177684,
 "country": "Afghanistan",
 "countryInfo": {
  "_id": 4,
  "iso2": "AF",
  "iso3": "AFG",
  "lat": 33,
  "long": 65,
  "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/af.png"
 },
 "cases": 5226,
 "todayCases": 0,
 "deaths": 132,
 "todayDeaths": 0,
 "recovered": 648,
 "active": 4446,
 "critical": 7,
 "casesPerOneMillion": 134,
 "deathsPerOneMillion": 3,
 "tests": 18724,
 "testsPerOneMillion": 481,
 "continent": "Asia"
 },
 {
.
.
.
etc
```

Node.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");

const url = "https://disease.sh/v2/countries/";


app.get("/getData",function(req,res){
  https.get(url, function(response){
      console.log(response.statusCode)

      response.on("data",function(data){
        const covidData=JSON.parse(data)
        // const cases = covidData.cases
        res.send({covidData});
      })

    }, function(err){ console.log(err)})
  }
)


app.listen(5000,function(){
  console.log("listening at port 5000")
})
```

Comment: The error being returned is 500 , you should check the details of that error and fix it

Comment: I added error checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an issue like this, the first thing to do is to check for the error, in other words add a handler for the error to see what's going wrong

```
  https.get('https://disease.sh/v2/countries', function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode)

  }, function(err){ console.log(err)})
```

The error is connection refused, means it cannot connect to remote server, as you can see you are missing a slash in your url, to fix it:

```
  https.get('https://disease.sh/v2/countries/', function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode)

  }, function(err){ console.log(err)})
```

Or better just use the more clear version of `request`

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://disease.sh/v2/countries', function (error, response, body) {
  console.error('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', JSON.parse(body)[0].cases); // get cases from the country you specified Afghanistan
});
```

This is from their official docs, I just changed the url to yours.

You can test this request separately by bringing up node in your terminal, just type `node` and then try the request without the express server.

Comment: I added your code. I seem to be getting the first entry of the JSON but it wont seem to output in my console

Comment: Why do you mean exactly by `render`? when I ran it I got 82059 objects from your endpoint in the body

Comment: I'm trying to console.log({covidData}). I was hoping to get the json printed out in my console, but instead I'm just getting an error.

Comment: @AlfieTorres I updated the code,  I think you just needed to parse it as json. now it prints the cases in Afghanistan